# ReactJS SSR vs CSR - Is there a security risk to allowing endpoints to be viewed by anyone

Tags: reactjs, api, server-side-rendering

I am building an admin panel for my application and I am trying to decide whether or not to use SSR (Server side rendering) or CSR (Client side rendering).

The most prominent issue to using CSR is that it would be really easy to view the JS code and get all of my admin API endpoints. These are secured with on the backend and need a firebase token to access but my question is; is there more of a security risk if these are exposed?

Also are there any other risks using CSR on a admin panel?

Comment: What you're referring to is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity , or more specifically, the lack of it. This is not a real security but the lack of it may contribute to security risks. This totally depends on your specific case. Since the case is unknown, the question is not constructive.